# Which factors effects bundle size of the product and aot compitlations and build to organise below scenario?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-builder

What are the best practises to organise components, services in beolw scenarios.

In our products 70-80 components and each component has one injectable servie as well.

and maximum all dropdown options data are getting dynamically through the apis

means

```
  AComponent - Aservice,
  BComponent-Bservice,
  CComponent-Cservice
  DComponent-Dservice..................
```

Case:  as I said above all dropdowns are dynamic means and 
**AComponent injecets the Aservice, Bservice, Dservice** as so on

Current code is now organised like this using promises

```
 class Acomponent {
  constructor(private aservice: Aservice, private bservice: Bservice, private dservice: Dservice....) {}
  ngOnInit() {
   this.loading = true;
   this.aservice.getAData().then(res => {
    this.bservice.getBData().then(res => {
     this.cservice.getCData().then(res => {
      this.loading = false;

     })
    })
   })
  }
 }

 Aservice:
  class Aservice {
   getAData() {
    return this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_PRODUCTS')
   }

   class Bservice {
    getBData() {
     return this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_CUSTOMES')
    }

    class Cservice {
     getCData() {
      return this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_PRICELIST')
     }

    }
```

**appsettings.ts**

```
 export var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api';
```

In above case all are independent services functions , there is no dependency between each other. 
One thing to remeber after getting all data from all apis only I need to load page, 
and In apiurl in http until  port number one constant variable used after that route is hard coded

So I want to clean code using **angular forkjoin** using subscribers. in below solutions which is the best practice

Solution1 :   in component itself use the fork join

```
   class Acomponent {
    constructor(private aservice: Aservice, private bservice: Bservice, private dservice: Dservice....) {}
    ngOnInit() {
     this.loading = true;
     forkJoin(
      this.aservice.getData(),
      this.bservice.getBData() this.cservice.getCData()
     )
     responses.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res) // [{}, {}, {}] // lenght 3
     })



    }
   }


   Solution2:
    (a) class Aservice {
     getData() {
       return forkJoin(this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_PRODUCTS/producttype="xoc"',
          this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_CUSTOMES/customertype="bix"'
           this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + '/RMAN_PRICELIST')
          }
         }
         (or)
         (b) apiurls.ts
         export var apis = {
          produts: '/RMAN_PRODUCTS/RMAN_PRODUCTS/producttype="xoc"',
          customers: '/RMAN_CUSTOMES/customertype="bix"',
          pricelist: '/RMAN_PRICELIST'
         }
         A.service.ts

         class Aservice {

          getData() {
            return forkJoin(this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + apis.produts: ,
               this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + apis.customers:
                this.http.get(appSettings.apiUrl + apis.pricelist)
               }
              }
              class Acomponent {
               constructor(private aservice: Aservice) {}
               ngOnInit() {
                this.aservice: getData().subscibe(res => {
                 console.log(res) // [{}, {}, {}] // lenght 3
                })
               }
```

Points To Notice

> In all components

```
 . Above two approaches are doing same but my dought is which will be better and best practice? and why?

 . with  solution1 there is less work modify code in all components(60-80)

 . In solution 2 (a), (b) we can remove services like Bservice, Cservice from componentA

 . with Solution 2 (a) api urls are hard coded, twise, thires if required more time time .
```

My Manager told that less chances to change parameter values in api like 
    ex:  `'/RMAN_PRODUCTS/RMAN_PRODUCTS/producttype="xoc"'          // "xoc"(parameter)`

. But even I am thinking If I follow the secode approach (solution 2(b)) even If i change param,or route then its' very easy and less time taken to change it)

```
 >Doubts:::
   1. Inject the services in componets is the good approch or not ?
   2. Is many services injcetion will take more time to bundle and comipe?
   3. Which solution is good and why in your words with clear explation?

 Please help me, Before Going to work I want to consider all facts. 

  Thanks in advance
```

Comment: PLEASE, make some effort to write proper English sentences and be clear enough. Your issue is totally not understable. Also don't forget that we're not in your project, so pander to us and use simple examples, not complicated ones.

Comment: @Maryannah where you did not understoode please tell me